# Why my system says have a 32 bit cpu?

Tags: cpu-architecture

When execute:

```bash
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias;
cpu:type:x86,ven0002fam0019mod0021:feature:,0000,
```

Says have a 32 bit cpu, but have a ryzen 7 5800X3D, is a 64 bit cpu, what happens?

```bash
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Ryzen | head -n 1
model name  : AMD Ryzen 7 5800X3D 8-Core Processor
$ uname -i
x86_64
```

`modalias` file is not the cpu architecture representation?

Comment: x86 is not 32-bit in that context, It's just less specific then x86_64. One have x86-16 as well etc (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86). The `modalias` also includes vendor, family and model + feature-list.

Comment: Where does it say 32 bit? It says `x86` which is ether 32bit or 64bit. It also says x86_64, that is the 64bit variant. MS use the word x64 for 64 bit, which they contrast with x86 (which I assume they think is a 86 bit processor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cpu/modalias` show you:

`cpu:type:x86,ven0002fam0019mod0021:feature:[FEATURE LIST]`

`x86` in this context does not mean 32-bit, but that it is part of [the x86 instruction set architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) family where one have both Intel and AMD. The x86 architecture has 16, 32 and 64 bits.

It further say (which is "translated" in `/proc/cpuinfo`):

- vendor: 0x02 (2)  (AMD, Intel has 0 etc.) [See for example asm/processor.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/10d4879f9ef01cc6190fafe4257d06f375bab92c/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L160)
- family: 0x19 (25)
- model:  0x21 (33)

The kernel uses the [CPUID instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) (specific for x86) to get a list of features from the CPU. (The article show how this can be done using assembly).

You are interested in long-mode (LM) which is identified by 61 (`0x003D`) in the feature list.

Did a crude script to list the features by parsing [the `cpufeatures.h` file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/10d4879f9ef01cc6190fafe4257d06f375bab92c/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h) from the kernel source:

```bash
#! /bin/bash -

# Hash-like map with features from cpufeatures.h
# An ugly and likely unreliable sed parse :P

# https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/10d4879f9ef01cc6190fafe4257d06f375bab92c/arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeatures.h
declare -A features=()
while IFS=$'\t' read -r a b c; do
    a=$((a))
    x=$(printf "%04X" $a)
    features[$x]="$(printf "%s %3d\t%-24s\t%s" "$x" "$a" "$b" "$c")"
done< <(sed -n '
s;^#define X86_FEATURE_\([^ ]\+\)\s\+(\([^)]\+\)) /\*\(.*\) \*/$;\2\t\1\t\3;p' \
    cpufeatures.h)

# Give any argument to script to print all
# possible features defined in cpufeatures.h:
if [ $# = 1 ]; then
    printf 'cpufeatures:\n'
    printf '%s\n' "${features[@]}" | sort
    printf '\n'
fi

# Print all features from system's CPU.
# Unknown are denoted by * (N/A)
printf '/sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias features:\n'
while IFS= read -r feature; do
    ent=${features[$feature]}
    if [ -z "$ent" ]; then
        printf '%s %3d*\t(N/A)\n' "$feature" "$((0x$feature))"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$ent"
    fi
done< <(sed 's/^.*feature:,\?\(.*\),\?$/\1/;s/,/\n/g' \
    /sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias | sort)
```

Gives you a full list like:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/modalias features:
0000   0    FPU                          Onboard FPU
0001   1    VME                          Virtual Mode Extensions
0002   2    DE                           Debugging Extensions
0003   3    PSE                          Page Size Extensions
0004   4    TSC                          Time Stamp Counter
0005   5    MSR                          Model-Specific Registers
0006   6    PAE                          Physical Address Extensions
0007   7    MCE                          Machine Check Exception
0008   8    CX8                          CMPXCHG8 instruction
0009   9    APIC                         Onboard APIC
000B  11    SEP                          SYSENTER/SYSEXIT
000C  12    MTRR                         Memory Type Range Registers
000D  13    PGE                          Page Global Enable
000E  14    MCA                          Machine Check Architecture
... and so on
```

Checking for long-mode this should for example give you:

```bash
 ./cpufeatures | grep Long
003D  61    LM                           Long Mode (x86-64, 64-bit support)
```

The list should be partially the same as `flags` in `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are misinterpreting the info look [here](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2009/05/how-to-confirm-if-your-cpu-is-32bit-or-64bit/)

What you're looking for is flag: lm. It stands for X86_FEATURE_LM, **the Long Mode (64bit) support**. If you can find the "lm" flag among your CPU flags, this means you're looking at a 64bit **capable** processor.

The keyword here is capable.

Answer (score 0):

**`x86_64`** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)) identified as 64-bit already in your question.